# Unable to view plots on .md file in GitHub

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, knitr, figure

I created a R markdown file on R Studio and used the Knit function to create an html file. Eventually, .md file and html files were created in my working directory. Also, a figures folder/directory was created automatically. And hence, I pushed all the changes made to my GitHub repository.

Now, my problem here is when I open the .md (markdown) file on GitHub, it doesn't view the plots. It shows the link to it though. Attached a snippet for reference.

[image: .md file on github]

I tried a couple of things which didn't work:

1. Added the below code chunk

   ```
   library(knitr)
   opts_chunk$set(dev="png")
   ```
2. Impended ?raw=true end of the image link. I changed

   ![](PA1_template_files/figure-html/total number of steps taken each day-1.png) to

   ![](PA1_template_files/figure-html/total number of steps taken each day-1.png?raw=true)

I am using:

- R-Studio Version : 1.0.143
- Windows 7

Comment: I think this is expected. the "md" files are intermediate and are not intended to use directly. You should view the html file in a web browser, you pic should be there.  if you would like to host the output html page online, you can try gh-pages

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @TCZhang Thank you for your response. I agree with your answer, that is my understanding too. But unfortunately, the assignment I'm working on requires plots to be viewed on markdown file. Strange!

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the feedback and edit. I'm sorry, this is my first post here and looks like I have not done a great job. I shall follow guidelines better next time.

Comment: In that case, you may upload the image to imgur and try ![](imgurl) to embed it in your file.

Comment: @TCZhang Thank you for the suggestion. I have solved the problem and have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem!

I removed spaces from code chunk names and it worked.

I can now view plots/figures in the markdown file.

One of the posts on R-studio support had me try this solution. Repeated google search helped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting global options in the .Rmd file as follows:

````
```{r global_options}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='Figs/')
```
````

Comment: Please, elaborate/provide a deeper answer on why this work. Paste code that just works without any explanation is not recommended as it won't teach anything to other visitors.